# Zend Framework 2 - Where Clause

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I would like to add a where clause with this method.

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->select();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

I have added like this.

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->select();
    $resultSet->where("status = ?", 1);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

But, it shown the below error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet::where()

Could you please help me to add WHERE, OR WHERE, GROUP and ORDER with above mentioned method.

Comment: Is `status` a field name here?

Comment: thanks. yes. Status column has 0 and 1 values. i like to select 1.

Comment: I assume you extend from `TableGateway`?

Comment: In this case add a `$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where(); //do more!` to `$this->select($where)`. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#zend-db-sql-where-zend-db-sql-having Also: **start to read the manual, please!** This is explained, see http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#basic-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you out:

```
    public function Profile($accountid)
    {
        $result = $this->select(function (Select $select) use ($accountid) {
            $select
                ->columns(array(
                    'datefrom',
                    'available',
                    'used',
                    'details'
                ))
                ->where($this->adapter->getPlatform()->quoteIdentifier('accountid') . ' = ' . $this->adapter->getPlatform()->quoteValue($accountid));
        });

        $row = $result->current();

        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception('could_not_find_row');
        }

        return $row;
    }
```

Comment: I found the use() to be helpful. I can't find anything on that declaration though. Is that a Zend thing or a PHP thing?

Comment: use() is a PHP thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `$sql->select()->where(array('status' => 1))` or `$table->select(array('status' => 1))` (annoying, wish they used the same syntax).

You pass where an associative array with the mapping `column => value` (and since it's an array you can give it multiple clauses). Diemuzi's way is good for complex identifiers but this is a more readable way for simple comparison.